# Finding French immigration records for ancestor from Spain who changed name?

Tags: 20th-century, immigration, france, spain

**My great grand parents** from my mother's side (born circa 1900) **left Spain** in the first quarter of the 20th century to move to **France** where my grand father was born in 1925. They left Spain because they were looking for better living conditions and started working as daily workers in the south east of France. My great grand father built my village's wine cellar among other things that are still standing today and became a great figure in my village.

I was very interested in trying to find out if they had relatives who stayed in Spain, but when **I asked my mom she couldn't answer** because her own father who passed away pretty young never told her. He did also not tell her **where they used to live** in Spain. Besides, when they moved to France they **shortened their last name** to only 3 letters so it is very difficult for me to find a trace of that.

Do you have any idea on how I could investigate on that without having to go to Spain to check that out?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  I think you should start with the earliest record that you can find for either of your great grandparents in France because that may trigger ideas about where they may have come from in Spain and/or what their name may have been.  Did they ever travel back to Spain?

Comment: Your great grandfather will have been born more than 100 years ago so our privacy policy in the [help/on-topic] provides no impediment to including full details about him.  If you wish to do that there is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it at any time.

Comment: Try to get birth registers of your relatives. Likely you will get extra data step by step.

Comment: @TrebiaProject I would love to but my aunts and uncles do not speek to my mom anymore as they fought when my grandparents died. When I asked them about any documents they said they had burned it all...

Comment: @mopmop well I was referring to the official state or local records available in France and further on in Spain. But I agree that making peaces is a good strategy as well.

Comment: Can you give us the names, even if they are shorter than the originals? It would help, of course.